# Attempted to load class "Memcached" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?

Tags: php, windows, symfony, localhost, memcached

I have setup existing symfony project to my local machine(windows). After composer install i get a error like this .

> ClassNotFoundException in Memcached.php line 6:
>
> Attempted to load class "Memcached" from the global namespace.
> Did you forget a "use" statement?

Comment: Please attach your `composer.json` file so we could have a look...

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this  issue?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

Without detailed look into your configuration, I can only offer you a checklist with which you could give it a shot and see which part is missing.

1. The quesiton is tagged under `symfony`, so I assume that you installed a bundle. Was it [leaseweb/memcache-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/leaseweb/memcache-bundle), or was some other?
2. Try examinging your `vendor` directory and try to identify if you have any of `Memcached` related classes.
3. If question to **(1)** is false, you may be missing some `psr-4` mappings. Try examining your `autoload.php` and look for `Memcached` specific namespace.
4. Do you actually have `php-memcached` php extension installed? Have you enabled it? Try running `php -m` and look for `php-memcached` or something like that.

Please provide more info and we might be able to narrow it down.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Download the php_memcached.dll from [here](https://github.com/lifenglsf/php_memcached_dll) and place it in the ext directory. If you are using a php version older than 7.3 also download the libmemcached.dll and place it in the php root directory. Don't forget to enable extension from the php.ini file.